# SSRS Date/Time Parameter changing how it is displayed on the report

Tags: reportviewer, ssrs-2008

Is there a possibility of changing how the SSRS DateTime parameters are displayed on the report,
i have a parameter with a date/time data type, when the report run, users see a date format that included time in it , users don't want to see time in the parameters, it should only be a date like <2/6/2010>, is there a way to do this in SSRS

Thanks in advance

Comment: @gbn I am trying to set up a date parameter, Its Data type is Date/Time, When i preview the Report on the report server, it does not show time, When i embed my report in a report viewer control of .NET, i receive time too eg (3/11/2010 10:22:07) , users want to see (3/11/2010) only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Embedding SSRS report on a .NET web form, using Report Viewer control, and pre-populating the date parameter with values, from code. The parameters after that will keep the same format as the date you provided them with from code.

so i was populating my parameter from C# like this

```
var startDate = DateTime.Now;
var parameters = new List<ReportParameter>
             { new ReportParameter("START_DATE", startDate.ToString())};
ConsumptionReportViewer.ServerReport.SetParameters(parameters);
```

this gave the START_DATE paremeter with dates of this format "3/9/2008 4:05:07 PM"
and later changing the dates from the calender input, the format remains the same

i changed the format on the code to

```
new ReportParameter("START_DATE", String.Format("{0:d}",startDate)
```

this gives the START_DATE paremeter wiht dates of this format "3/9/2008"
and now when i change the datees from the calender input, the format remains the same